# SQL query to sum and group hours and wages by day

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by, sum

Sorry it seems like a simple query but I am stuck on it. I am trying to get daily hours and wages from Totals table grouped by employee ID. The table has TimeinSeconds, WageAmount, EmpID, location and other information. 
I am using this:
Select EmpID, Loc, Sum(timeinseconds/3600.0) as Hours, Paydate, wageamt
from Totals
where loc = 'locID'
and paycode IN (paycodenames)
and date > (getdate()-21)
Group by EmpID, Loc, date, wageamt

But I am getting breakdown and not daily Totals by Emp. It works if I don't use wageamt in the query. So, how can I Sum on both hours and wages?

```
 EmpID  Loc Hours       Paydate     wageamt        

 112        7   0.733333    08/06/14    14.666667   
 112        7   2.533333    08/06/14    50.666667   
 112        7   4           08/06/14    80  
 112        7   1.25        08/07/14    25  
 112        7   4           08/07/14    80  
 200       81   3.983333    08/06/14    31.866667   
 450      703   3.733333    08/06/14    108.789333
```

I am using SQL 2008. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Use a GROUP BY and SUM like this:

```
select 
     EmpID
    ,Loc
    ,sum(Hours)   as Hours
    ,PayDate
    ,sum(WageAmt) as WageAmt
from DataTable
group by
     EmpID
    ,Loc
    ,PayDate
```

Comment: @user3271831: The only true thank you is an up-vote and an accept.